# Webpack does not exclude file specified in the exclude array

Tags: node.js, webpack

I have a large configuration file that I want to exclude from the build, I want to end up with two files:

```
--bundle.js
--config.js
```

I have tried multiple approaches:

Excluding the file:

```
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: [/node_modules/, /config\.js/]
  }
]
```

Or with absolute path:

```
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: [/node_modules/, path.join(__dirname, "config.js")]
  }
]
```

Putting the file in a directory and excluding the directory:

```
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: [/node_modules/, /config/]
  }
]
```

But it is always included in the final build.

Now it is probably important to mention (because I saw it in other questions), that this file is required in one of my app files. The config.js file contains a large javascript object and it requires other classes from other files that it requires for the config object (which are not used anywhere else in the bundle, its all configuration logic). I have also tried excluding that directory aswell, but that didn't work either.

I'm guessing what I am trying to do is just leave the "config.js" to be required by the bundle so it works as a supplementary file, so that I can still work with it, when the rest of the files are bundled.

**EDIT:** Now that I am thinking about it, I know that .json files are excluded by default, what if, instead of requiring my config.js file, I read it with fs? So it is still required but not with "require"?

Comment: I think you may be looking for https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/

Comment: @FelixKling as far as I understand it, this only works for packages that I have installed in my app? I dont see how I can utilize it for my config file and its dependencies, can you give me a little push?:)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it by utilizing readFileSync and eval:

```
const jsFile = eval(fs.readFileSync("./jsFile.js", "utf-8"));
```

Keep in mind that if you are requiring other files within that file, the paths change! They will **NOT** be relative to `jsFile.js`, but relative to the **file which reads the `jsFile.js`**

After that you simply include all of the files in the same hierarchical structure relative to the bundle, as it was in the project before you have bundled it.